# Template Unresolved Type - Setup Type - Dynamic Properties

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm wondering if someone knows what's going on here, and how to resolve it. I am using Vue3 v3.3.6., the Composition API, and TypeScript v4.9.5, and Volar.

The issue I'm having is in the template section of the Vue Component, where Typescript doesn't want/know-how to resolve the publisher variable (PublisherType), even though it is defined in the script.

```js
<template>
  <page-layout ref="page" :actions="actions" :breadcrumbs="breadcrumbs" @action="(item) => item.action()">
    <template #alerts>
      <v-alert v-if="!publisher" type="error" :dismissible="false" title="Error" text="Failed To Load Publisher"/>
    </template>
    <template #content="{state}">
        <div>{{ publisher }}</div>
    </template>
</template>
```

> Unresolved variable or type publisher

My setup() has a type of PageLayoutSetup, which is supposed to ensure that each page that uses the PageLayout component implements the required fields/methods/etc. In order to allow the component to export other fields I implemented dynamic properties in the PageLayoutSetup type.

```
export interface PageLayoutSetup {
  page: Ref<PageLayoutType | null>;
  actions: Ref<PageLayoutAction[]>;
  breadcrumbs: Ref<PageLayoutBreadcrumb[]>;
  refresh: () => void;
  [key: string]: any; //dynamic properties
}
```

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted, watch, computed } from "vue";
import PageLayout from '@/components/PageLayout.vue';
import type {
  PageLayoutSetup,
  PageLayoutType,
  PageLayoutAction,
  PageLayoutBreadcrumb,
} from "@/components/PageLayoutType";
import type { PublisherType } from '@/components/PublisherType';
import PublisherModel from '@/models/Publisher';
import { useRepo } from 'pinia-orm';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Publisher',
  components: {
    PageLayout,
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props): PageLayoutSetup { //<--- Here
    /** Data */
    const page = ref<PageLayoutType | null>(null);
    const publisher = ref<PublisherType | null>(null); //<--- Here
    const actions = ref<PageLayoutAction[]>([
       //code...
    ]);
    const breadcrumbs = computed((): PageLayoutBreadcrumb[] => [
      //code...
    ]);
    const repoPublishers = useRepo(PublisherModel);

    /** Methods */
    const refresh = (showLoading = true) => {
      //code...
    };

    /** Lifecycle Hooks */
    onMounted(() => {
      //code...
    });
    watch(() => props.id, () => {
      refresh();
    });

    return {
      page,
      publisher, //<--- Here
      actions,
      breadcrumbs,
      refresh,
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

I'm pretty confident that because publisher is a dynamic property, regardless of it's type being defined in the actual setup, that that's the issue. If I remove PageLayoutSetup from setup(), the template has no problem resolving the PublisherType.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to get PublisherType to resolve in the template while still keeping PageLayoutSetup on the setup, and not defining PublisherType in PageLayoutSetup?

If there is anything else I can provide, let me know.